# Указания пути к OpenSSL через SetDllDirectory

Tags: c++, qt, openssl

Я хочу использовать в своем приложения на QT ssl (https), QT уже скомпилирован с OpenSSL (т.е., взяты готовые библиотеки с официального сайта).

Помимо этого у меня есть дочернее приложение, которое также использует OpenSLL у себя, оно лежит в директории `/3-rd/someApp/` относительно основного приложения, и в папке у него уже лежат библиотеки OpenSLL ssleay32.dll и libeay32.dll.

Так вот, насколько я понимаю Qt5Network подгружает OpenSLL библиотеки через `LoadLibraryW`, значит путь к библиотекам можно установить через WIN API функцию `SetDllDirectory`, что я и делаю (`/3-rd/someApp/`), но получаю ошибку, свидетельствующую о том, что библиотеки OpenSLL не найдены. Проблема не в неправильно установленном пути - я перепробовал разные варианты. Если же я просто положу библиотеки OpenSSL в одной директории с основным приложением, все работает как надо.

QT использует какую-то свою архитектуру для загрузки библиотек в рантайме? Как можно указать QT, где он должен искать библиотеки?

Comment: В общем я нашел ответ на свой вопрос, оставлю здесь если кому пригодится в будущем: 

OpenSLL библиотеки подгружаются через QSystemLibrary::load(метод loadOpenSslWin32 в qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp) и могут находится только в PATH или в директории с приложениям. Установка пути в SetDllDirectory никак не повлияет на этот процесс.

Comment: Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.